# API key with Google Document AI

Tags: curl, google-api, google-oauth, cloud-document-ai

I am using the form parser of Google Document ai.
The only way to authenticate that I have found is through gcloud command interface (`"Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)`).

Our application uses Google Vision too and just needs an API key (`https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=<the api key>`).

How can I use this way Google Document AI?

I have tried with the API key in `/apis/credentials` and I have tried to restrict the key to IP too and to document ai API, but all with the same result:

```bash
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -d @request.json https://eu-documentai.googleapis.com/v1beta3/projects/<project id>/locations/eu/processors/<processor id>:process?key=<api key>

{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The [Document AI Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/setup#auth) shows how to setup Authentication for the Document AI API.

Comment: If I understand the linked quickstart correctly, it exports an environment variable for a CLI. Is there a way to include authentication for a regular fetch request? For context: I'd like to authenticate with the Document AI api in a Google Apps Script project.

Answer (score 0):

> Request is missing required authentication credential.

Means that you have not sent any authorization with your request

The request you are attempting requires that you send an access token along as a bearer token

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" http://www.example.com
```

You appear to only be sending an API key which will only grant you access to public data not private user data.

Comment: with vision the application seems to send only an api key (the header has only a content type) and the problem for me is that I don't want to use gcloud in order to obtain the access token...

Comment: With the error message you are getting it says that it requires authorization.  Which means you need an access token.